# Разделить строку по словам и вставить слова в список

Tags: python, tkinter

задался себе вопросом, есть строка:

```
str = 'мясо, котлеты, овощи'
```

Мне нужно разделить эти слова по разделителю ", " (запятая с пробелом).
И в итоге вставить эти разделенных слова в список(list). Чтобы было:

```
list[0] = 'мясо'
list[1] = 'котлеты'
list[2] = 'овощи'
```

Буду благодарен за помощь. Что-то у меня не получается сделать это с помощью метода split

Answer (score 1):

```
str = 'мясо, котлеты, овощи'
list = str.split(', ')
```

Но в будущем советую не называть переменные `list` и `str`, т.к. это типы данных в Питоне.